# How to join 2 queries in Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am in Python and I have the above 2 queries which I want to join them in 1.

```
def fly_away(session, line_id):
    query = session.\
              query(
                Pilot.Id,
                Pilot.EntityId,
                Pilot.From
              ).\
    filter(Pilot.Id == line_id)

    query = session.\
                  query(
                    CTower.Id,
                    CTower.Time,
                    CTower.Associate
                  ).\
    filter(CTower.Associate == line_id)
```

I tried to use join but I dont know how to use it correctly. Can I have some help please?

Comment: The query makes no sense to me. Please, show us how the data looks like and what are you trying to get from it.

Comment: The queries in my question are 2. I want to join them. I want to get data from two different tables .. with one query.. the data and the tables are written on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fly_away(session, line_id):
  query = session.\
          query(
            Pilot.Id,
            Pilot.EntityId,
            Pilot.From,
          ).\
          outerjoin(CTower, Pilot.Id == CTower.Associate).\
          filter(Pilot.Id == line_id)     
  return query
```

this is what I am trying now.. and its working .. but not exactly as I want

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what database are you using and what driver are you using to connect python to the database but I will post the sql query that will do the job. I am sure, you can use it with your driver.

```
SELECT Pilot.Id, Pilot.EntityId, Pilot.From, CTower.Id, CTower.Time, CTower.Associate 
FROM Pilot, CTower 
WHERE CTower.Associate == Pilot.Id
```

Comment: @TakisMakis What is session object?

Comment: its something irrelevent on how to join these two queries.

Comment: @TakisMakis Well, I have joined those two queries as you can see from my answer, if that is what you want. If you want to run it in python, you should give more info about stuff you use.